# Water coming down PVC pipe from ceiling to furnace

Tags: hvac

Water comes down the PVC vent pipe to my furnace and leaks out at the elbow. Water seems to come even when the furnance is turned off.  I had a furnance man come out.  He said there is a leak at the roof, as it had been raining.

Now, it is days after he left.  We have not had any rain.

What type of repair person would I need to call?

Comment: What makes you think that you shouldn't call a Roof Man to repair the leak in the roof?  The Furnace Man already told you what the problem was, right?

Answer (score 1):

You likely just need caulk from a poor HVAC guy install using flat metal that is now sagged (needs to be crowned) & letting water in as well as causing condensation water whenever the furnace runs. If you aren't comfortable with getting on the roof to see if you just need caulk, then absolutely get a Roofer to address it.